Unable to inject custom @JsonFilter in SpringBootTest
I have a data class for which I use a custom JsonFilter
@JsonFilter(value = "conditional_serializers")
data class DocumentRequest(
  val someField: String? = null,
  val someOtherField: String? = null
)

In my code I am using com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-60:2.21.1 dependency to define the custom filter for my db mapping.
private val theFilter =
  object : SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
    override fun serializeAsField(
      pojo: Any?,
      jgen: JsonGenerator?,
      provider: SerializerProvider?,
      writer: PropertyWriter?
    ) {
      provider?.setAttribute(DO_NOT_SERIALIZE, true)
      super.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider, writer)
    }

    override fun include(writer: BeanPropertyWriter?): Boolean {
      return true
    }

    override fun include(writer: PropertyWriter?): Boolean {
      return true
    }
  }

val filters = SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter(CONDITIONAL_SERIALIZERS, theFilter).setFailOnUnknownId(false)

class HibernateJacksonConfig : ObjectMapperSupplier {
  companion object {
    const val DO_NOT_SERIALIZE = "do_not_serialize"
    const val CONDITIONAL_SERIALIZERS = "conditional_serializers"
  }

  override fun get(): ObjectMapper {
    return jacksonObjectMapper()
      .registerModules(JavaTimeModule())
      .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
      .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
      // TODO: add handling for AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS:
      //         .disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS)
      // TODO: test that it is actually working (e.g. Retailer.isOwnRetailer serialisation)
      .setDateFormat(SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"))
      .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
      .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())
      .setFilterProvider(filters)
  }
}



While running the applicaiton, this is working perfectly fine. I have define a property in hibernate.properties as hibernate.types.jackson.object.mapper=com.app.HibernateJacksonConfig 
But while I am writing a spring boot test, I am consistently getting an exception for all the classes that use @JsonFilter("conditional_serializers")
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not serialize object of java type: BasicJavaType(com.app.DocumentRequest)
  at org.hibernate.type.format.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatMapper.toString(JacksonJsonFormatMapper.java:56)
  at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JsonJdbcType.toString(JsonJdbcType.java:109)
  at org.hibernate.dialect.AbstractPostgreSQLJsonPGObjectType.access$000(AbstractPostgreSQLJsonPGObjectType.java:29)
  at org.hibernate.dialect.AbstractPostgreSQLJsonPGObjectType$1.doBind(AbstractPostgreSQLJsonPGObjectType.java:48)
  at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:61)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.JdbcValueBindingsImpl.lambda$beforeStatement$0(JdbcValueBindingsImpl.java:87)
  at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.spi.BindingGroup.forEachBinding(BindingGroup.java:51)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.JdbcValueBindingsImpl.beforeStatement(JdbcValueBindingsImpl.java:85)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.performNonBatchedMutation(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:102)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorSingleNonBatched.performNonBatchedOperations(MutationExecutorSingleNonBatched.java:40)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.execute(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:52)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.doStaticInserts(InsertCoordinator.java:171)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.coordinateInsert(InsertCoordinator.java:112)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2865)
  at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:102)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:631)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:498)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:363)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
  at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1415)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:496)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2325)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1988)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439)
  at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:169)
  at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:267)
  at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:561)
  ... 102 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot resolve PropertyFilter with id 'conditional_serializers'; no FilterProvider configured
  at app//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
  at app//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1330)
  ```


How do I fix my test to add this conditional_serializers property.
